# discord.py report system discord.py | MissingRequiredArgument

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Okay so I think I got the right code down but I don't know what argument to use. If anyone can help please do.

Code:

```py
@client.command()
async def report(ctx, *, report):
  # values
  user = ctx.author
  server = ctx.guild.name
  channel = client.get_channel(1009201586586783785)
  # Report Text
  if report == None:
      # Error
      await ctx.send("Enter your report! example : r!report {your report here}")
  else:
      # Success
      await ctx.send("We have sent your report to **DisReport Hub** to be reviewed!")
      report = discord.Embed(title=f"{user.name} sent an report!", description="-----", color=discord.Colour.blurple())
      report.add_field(name=f"Report from - {server}: ", value=f"{report}")
      await channel.send(embed=report)
```

Error message:

```
 line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: report is a required argument that is missing.
```

Comment: Try not to make the function and argument name the same. You can do something like report_command and under the decorator change the discord command to “report”

Comment: yeah I just realized I did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly give it a default of `None` if want it to default. Otherwise, it will give you that exception, which will lead to the error being printed to the console if it wasn't already handled.

```py
@client.command()
async def report(ctx, *, report: str = None):
  # values
  user = ctx.author
  server = ctx.guild.name
  channel = client.get_channel(1009201586586783785)
  # Report Text
  if report is None:  # sidenote: prefer `is` when comparing to `None`
      # Error
      await ctx.send("Enter your report! example : r!report {your report here}")
  else:
      # Success
      await ctx.send("We have sent your report to **DisReport Hub** to be reviewed!")
      report = discord.Embed(title=f"{user.name} sent an report!", description="-----", color=discord.Colour.blurple())
      report.add_field(name=f"Report from - {server}: ", value=f"{report}")
      await channel.send(embed=report)
```